# Variable label not change after used tbl_merge in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I can't change "variable label" when  I used **tbl_merge**., how to change the label.?
label=list() not function in **tbl_merge***.

```
Table.7<-cov %>% 
  select(status,sex,ht,dm,chd,ca,pneu,copd,ards1)
label=list(sex="Sex", 
           ht="Hypertension",
           dm="Diabetes",
           chd="Cardiac Dieases",
           ca="Cancer", 
           pneu="Pneumonia", 
           asthma= "Asthma",
           copd="COPD", 
           ards1="ARDS")

tb_u<-tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    data = Table.7,
    y = status, 
    method.args = list(family = binomial(link = logit)),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  )
  
tb_m<- glm(status ~ ht+sex+dm+chd+ca+pneu+copd+ards1,data=Table.7,
           family = binomial(link = logit)) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE,
                  (attr(Table.7$sex, "Sex1")) )

  tbl_merge(list(tb_u, tb_m),
  tab_spanner = c("**Univariate**", "**Multivariate**")) %>% 
  bold_labels() %>% 
  as_flex_table()
```

See the output following below:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7C6j.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. That will help people create a clean answer.

Comment: Echoing @user1357015, including code we can run on our machines is important for providing a complete response to your question. Briefly, there are two ways to get the labels set up: 1.  Use the `tbl_regression(label=)` argument to assign the labels. 2. Assign the labels in the source data set using the `labelled::set_variable_labels()` function, and the labels in the data frame will be carried through into the summary tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use label in tbl_regression instead of tbl_merge

```
tb_u<-tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    data = Table.7,
    y = status, 
    method.args = list(family = binomial(link = logit)),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    label = label
  )
```